# Failing to get condition to work with div?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to have the ball sized to the prompt of the user upon entering it and something doesn't work, can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h1 {
        color: white;
    }
    div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: 0.3s;
        line-height: 50px;

    .ball4 {
        background-color: brown;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div class="ball4" onclick="onBall4Click()">
    PROMPT
</div>

<script>

    
    function onBall4Click() {
        var ball4 = document.querySelector('.ball4');
        var ball4Size = prompt("Size of ball? ");

        if (ball4Size > 1000) {
            alert("Too big!")
        } else {
            var ball4Size = size;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance to the helpers.

Comment: You didn't define `size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this is what you want with your JavaScript:

```
function onBall4Click() {
    var ball4 = document.querySelector('.ball4');
    var ball4Size = prompt("Size of ball? ");

    if (ball4Size > 1000) {
        alert("Too big!")
    } else {
        ball4.style.width = ball4Size;
        ball4.style.height = ball4Size;
    }
}
```

You were using an undefined variable rather than setting the actual size of the element. Also, I believe you still need to make the element a ball at this point because it is just a brown div right now.